# Proving $\exists$ infinitely many whole numbers that are not divisible by $n\in \mathbb{W}, \ n\gt 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-explanation

I have started studying logic from [this](http://eldar.mathstat.uoguelph.ca/dashlock/math4140/) source. I was trying the problems and got stuck on the following one:

> Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{W}$ and that $n\gt 1$. Prove that $\exists$ infinitely many positive whole numbers that are not whole number multiples of $n$.

I tried the following:

Let $a$ be non-whole number multiple of $n$. By Euclid's Lemma we have $a=nq+r$ with $r$ satisfying the stronger inequality $0\lt r \lt n$. Clearly every number of the form $n(q+k)+r$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ can be rewritten as $nq'+r$. Since the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is $\infty$ therefore there must be  infinitely many $a$ satisfying the condition. Hence, proved.

Is this correct? Is there any discrepancy in the proof? I would also like to get an explanation from the perspective of formal logic. Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91781/discussion-on-question-by-paras-khosla-proving-exists-infinitely-many-whole-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ n>1\ $ is an integer , the (infinite many) positive integers of the form $$kn+1$$ where $\ k\ $ is a positive integer , are obviously not a multiple of $\ n\ $, otherwise we would have $\ n\mid 1\ $ and therefore $\ n=1\ $.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you're trying to say.

Comment: Your object is to prove that for every integer $n>1$ there are infinite many positive integers NOT being a multiple of $n$, a number of the form $kn+1$ cannot be a multiple, so the proof is almost trivial.

Comment: Yes that is true but does not proving it for $0\lt r\lt n$ actually give a generalized proof?

Comment: @ParasKhosla OK, this is not difficult either. If $0<r<n$, then the integer cannot have the form $kn$ with some positive integer $k$ because in this case (due to the uniqueness of the number $r$) , we would have $r=0$ which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Exactly that's what we're supposed to prove that there are infinitely many numbers NOT of the form $kn$. I think we're on the same page but not on the same line.

Comment: We can choose infinite many positive integers $k$ and for each such $k$, $kn+1$ is not a multiple of $n$.

Comment: And neither is $kn+r$ for $r\ne 0$ and $0\lt r\lt n$. I got it. Thanks @Peter Cheers:))

Comment: Is my version of the proof that's been stated in the OP totally correct as well?

Comment: Yes, correct. You showed that for every $k$, a non-multiple exist and that there are infinite many such $k$